# How to increase Permgen size in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I got frequently

```
perm gen error
```

. how to increase Permgen size in eclipse. what is the way to increase Permgen space in eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the size of perm gen in config or .ini file packed with eclipse.

You need to add one line

```
 -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

at the end

Answer (score 1):

You can better try `-XX:MaxPermSize=128M` rather than `-XX:MaxPermGen=128M` or

add  `-XX:MaxPermSize=256m`

Also check [Understanding and avoiding the Java Permgen Space error](http://www.integratingstuff.com/2011/07/24/understanding-and-avoiding-the-java-permgen-space-error/) and [Classloader leaks: the dreaded "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space" exception](http://frankkieviet.blogspot.ca/2006/10/classloader-leaks-dreaded-permgen-space.html)

Answer (score 0):

if you use eclipse IDE than with use of it you can change the VM argument

```
double click on the server > open Lunch Configuration > Arguments > VM Arguments
```

and append below two lines in your VM Arguments field

```
-Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

it will sure solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

I test som solutions but this command is solved:

run your eclipse with this command

```
eclipse -vmargs -XX:PermSize=64M -XX:MaxPermSize=128M
```